# How do I get a List of programs connected to internet in linux?

Tags: linux, process, internet-connection

In linux, how can I get a list of programs that are currently connected to (and are receiving data) from the Internet?

Commands like iftop are good but does not show statistics based on process.

Comment: on my laptop lsof returns 500K output, not usable.

Comment: grep can find what you want and/or see the man page for options on restricting the output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`netstat` will show you all established connections.  Use `-p` for it to show the process associated with each one.  It won't show you anything about the amount of data they're receiving though.

Comment: it does not show current connections, but only shows connection established (/closed/...) from time of running netstat. And its more like a log file and (needs further interpretation) than something easily usable.

Comment: You did ask for a list of programs currently connected, that's what this does.  You might have more luck with something like `ntop`, but I've never used that.

Answer (score 2):

you can use lsof utility which lists information about files opened by processes

```
lsof -i
```

will show used internet resources only

Comment: thanks, but the better answer would be: `lsof -P -i -n | cut -f 1 -d " "| uniq | tail -n +2`

Comment: is there a monitoring option that keeps looking for programs?

Comment: @barraponto: Use watch